# Spacetime diagram of Rindler's lenght contraction paradox

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I'm struggling to draw properly the spacetime diagram for Rindler's lenght contraction paradox as exposed here:

https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1937789

How the spacetime diagram draw becomes?

Comment: similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox, and actually yours is also explained there

Comment: It's similar but, I don't think that is the SAME space-time diagram. In rindler's article he deals with acceleration.

Comment: The problem I see with making a diagram is that you now need two spatial dimensions, horizontal and vertical, and you cannot include that in a 2D minkowski diagram